# How can I display a multigraph with different colored edges?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, bugs, version-9

I'm new to Mathematica(version 9) and I'm trying to display a multigraph with different colored edges.  Here's my code so far:

```
G = {{1 -> 2, 1},  {2 -> 3, 1},  {3 -> 4, 1}, {4 -> 5, 1},
     {5 -> 6, 1},  {6 -> 7, 1},  {7 -> 8, 1}, {8 -> 9, 1},
     {9 -> 1, 1},  {1 -> 2, 2},  {2 -> 3, 2}, {3 -> 4, 2},
     {4 -> 5, 2},  {5 -> 6, 2},  {6 -> 7, 2}, {7 -> 8, 2},
     {8 -> 1, 2},  {1 -> 2, 3},  {2 -> 3, 3}, {3 -> 4, 3},
     {4 -> 5, 3},  {5 -> 6, 3},  {6 -> 7, 3}, {7 -> 1, 3},
     {1 -> 2, 4},  {2 -> 3, 4},  {3 -> 4, 4}, {4 -> 5, 4},
     {5 -> 6, 4},  {6 -> 1, 4},  {1 -> 2, 5}, {2 -> 3, 5},
     {3 -> 4, 5}, {4 -> 5, 5},   {5 -> 1, 5}}

GraphPlot[G,                
    EdgeRenderingFunction -> (Switch[#3, 1, {Black,  Line[#1]},
                                         2, {Red,    Line[#1]},
                                         3, {Blue,   Line[#1]},
                                         4, {Green,  Line[#1]},
                                         5, {Purple, Line[#1]}] &),
    VertexLabeling -> True,
    Method -> "CircularEmbedding",
    MultiedgeStyle -> All]
```

[image: example bug]

This draws a graph with only a few of its edges and gives many "Switch is not a graphics primitive or directive." errors.  How can I get this code to draw all of the edges properly?

Thanks,

Corey

Comment: It works fine with version 8 (at least I saw no warnings). [Here is the result.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3TJzw.png)

Comment: Weird.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's true, version 9 gives an error. It's because it can't handle the labels for more than one undirected edge between the same vertices. E.g., you can try just one duplicate edge in this shortened graph (first and last entries are duplicates): `g2 = {{1 -> 2, 1}, {2 -> 3, 1}, {3 -> 4, 1}, {4 -> 5, 1}, {5 -> 6,1}, {6 -> 7, 1}, {7 -> 8, 1}, {8 -> 9, 1}, {9 -> 1, 1}, {1 -> 2,7}};GraphPlot[g2, VertexLabeling -> True]` Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Your code also works as written in version 7.

Comment: also works fine in version 11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to make a workaround substitute function for your particular `GraphPlot` that avoids the error with `VertexLabeling` by first drawing an *unlabeled* graph and then correcting the colors according to the `Switch` function you specified. In the initial plot, the edges are relatively easy to filter out because they appear in a single `Line` command. With this, I eventually arrived at this:

```
graphPlotColored[data_, colorFn_] := Module[{
   lines,
   edgdeLabelsSorted,
   unlabeledGraph = 
    GraphPlot[data[[All, 1]], VertexLabeling -> True, 
     Method -> "CircularEmbedding", MultiedgeStyle -> All]
   },
  lines = First@Cases[unlabeledGraph, Line[l_] :> l, Infinity];
  edgdeLabelsSorted = 
   Flatten@MapIndexed[
     Cases[data, {Rule @@ #, _}, Infinity][[Last@#2, 2]] &, 
     Gather[Map[#[[{1, -1}]] &, lines]], {2}];
  unlabeledGraph /. 
   Line[l_] :> 
    MapThread[{colorFn[#2], Line[#1]} &, {lines, edgdeLabelsSorted}]
  ]

g = {{1 -> 2, 1}, {2 -> 3, 1}, {3 -> 4, 1}, {4 -> 5, 1}, {5 -> 6, 
    1}, {6 -> 7, 1}, {7 -> 8, 1}, {8 -> 9, 1}, {9 -> 1, 1}, {1 -> 2, 
    2}, {2 -> 3, 2}, {3 -> 4, 2}, {4 -> 5, 2}, {5 -> 6, 2}, {6 -> 7, 
    2}, {7 -> 8, 2}, {8 -> 1, 2}, {1 -> 2, 3}, {2 -> 3, 3}, {3 -> 4, 
    3}, {4 -> 5, 3}, {5 -> 6, 3}, {6 -> 7, 3}, {7 -> 1, 3}, {1 -> 2, 
    4}, {2 -> 3, 4}, {3 -> 4, 4}, {4 -> 5, 4}, {5 -> 6, 4}, {6 -> 1, 
    4}, {1 -> 2, 5}, {2 -> 3, 5}, {3 -> 4, 5}, {4 -> 5, 5}, {5 -> 1, 
    5}};

graphPlotColored[g, (Switch[#, 1, Black, 2, Red, 3, Blue, 4, Green, 5,
     Purple] &)]
```

[image: graph]

The way this works is that `data` is assumed to have edge labels for every edge, as in the example `g`. Then I make `unlabeledGraph` without those labels, and collect the raw edge `lines` in it. My observation on which everything is based is that each element in `lines` numbers the starting and end points by exactly the same numbers as the vertices in the graph. If the line is curved, there are other numbers in the line (referencing interpolating points in the `GraphicsComplex` of the graph), but they have higher numbers.

So I can establish a correspondence between each element of `lines` and the corresponding elements of `data`; and for multiple edges between identical vertices this correspondence is made unique by following the order in which lines appear in `unlabeledGraph`. This is what `edgdeLabelsSorted` is for. For each edge, it picks the label of an element in `data` that has the same end points.

Finally, I post-process `unlabeledGraph` with a rule that prepends each edge line with a graphics directive specified by `colorFn`, with the argument given by the label found in `edgdeLabelsSorted`.

Since this isn't supposed to be a general solution, I simply put the options from your example into the function `unlabeledGraph` by hand. This could be customized and extended further. But at least it seems to work for the type of graph you're looking at.