# Isomorphism of colored multigraphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks, igraphm

Recently I discovered for myself IGraphM package and find it really great!

```
<< IGraphM`
```

I am still learning its basic functionality. I need to verify isomorphism of a large set of graphs. I have already simplified them to avoid directed edges as they possibly are harder to treat. However, they still possess 3 features:

- Colored vertices
- Colored edges
- There could be more than 1 edge connecting some of the vertices

Thus, they are colored multigraphs. In the manual to the `IGVF2IsomorphicQ`function it is written that

> VF2 supports vertex coloured and edge coloured graphs. A colour specification consists of one of more of the "VertexColors" and "EdgeColors" options.

In a different place it is also stated that

> Additionally, IGIsomorphicQ[] and IGSubisomorphicQ[] try to select the best algorithm for the given graphs. For graphs without multiple edges, they use igraph's default algorithm selection. For multigraphs, they use VF2 after internally transforming the multigraphs to an edge coloured simple graph.

Thus, we seems to be on the safe side and can try one example

```
gr[1]={1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 8, 8 <-> 9, 9 <-> 4, 1 <-> 10, 10 <-> 11, 11 <-> 2, 5 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 3 <-> 6, 6 <-> 7, 4 <-> 7, 5 <-> 7}
vr[1]=<|8 -> 3, 10 -> 3, 9 -> 7, 11 -> 7|>
ed[1]=<|6 <-> 7 -> 10|>

gr[2]={1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 8, 8 <-> 9, 9 <-> 3, 4 <-> 10, 10 <-> 11, 11 <-> 2, 5 <-> 5, 3 <-> 3, 5 <-> 6, 5 <-> 6, 6 <-> 7, 1 <-> 7, 4 <-> 7}
vr[2]=<|8 -> 3, 10 -> 3, 9 -> 7, 11 -> 7|>
ed[2]=<|6 <-> 7 -> 10|>
```

Let us visualize them first:

```
decorateGraph[con_, vrts_, edgs_] := Module[{g, gv},
  g = Graph[con];
  gv = Fold[SetProperty[{#1, #2}, 
  {VertexStyle -> ColorData[60, vrts[[Key[#2]]] ], VertexSize -> Medium}] &, g, 
    Keys[vrts]];
  Fold[SetProperty[{#1, #2}, 
     EdgeStyle -> {ColorData[60, edgs[[Key[#2]]]], Thick}] &, gv, 
   Keys[edgs]]
  ]

GraphicsRow[
{decorateGraph[Graph[gr[1]], vr[1], ed[1]],
 decorateGraph[Graph[gr[2]], vr[2], ed[2]]}, 
   Dividers -> Center, FrameStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Blue]]
```

They look quite different:
[image]

Now we use `IGVF2IsomorphicQ` to check the isomorphism

```
IGVF2IsomorphicQ[{Graph[gr[1]], "VertexColors" -> vr[1], "EdgeColors" -> ed[1]}, {Graph[gr[2]], "VertexColors" -> vr[2], "EdgeColors" -> ed[2]}]
```

**But the result is not what I've expected:**

`IGraphM::vf2nmg: VF2 does not support multigraphs.`

How to deal with this problem? Is it at all possible? I appreciate your help.

Comment: None of the isomorphism algorithms in the core [igraph](http://igraph.org/) library support multigraphs, but several support coloured graphs. It is possible to transform the multigraph isomorphism problem to a coloured simple graph isomorphism problem.  Simply count the multiplicity of each edge and use that number of the colour of the edge.  I implemented this for `IGIsomorphicQ`.  It is the only builtin function that supports multigraphs, but it does not support colours.

Comment: If you need to work with coloured multigraphs, you will need to somehow encode the both the current colour and the edge multiplicity into a new colour. There are multiple ways one could do this, though all I could think of are hackish.  E.g. you could construct new colours so that the `QuotientRemainder[newColour, n]` will be `{multiplicity, oldColour}`.  Of course, you would need to choose `n` correctly based on the colour count of both graphs you are comparing.

Comment: This takes a bit of work, and I do not have time to write an answer (hence the comments).  I won't have time for at least a week. I only logged in because I accidentally saw your question. I hope you can get it working based on this guidance.  You can see how the current multigraph -> coloured simple graph transformation works, and go from there: https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/blob/master/IGraphM/IGraphM.m#L1656

Comment: Another comment: please use the latest prerelease of IGraph/M, and take a look at the `IGVertexMap` and `IGEdgeMap` functions which may help you implement `decorateGraph` in a nicer way.

Comment: @Szabolcs It is probably the right method. However, there are some problems on the way. In a very general setup (that is not relevant for me) there could be  2 vertices connected by n edges each having different weights. The new effective weight must be properly computed to avoid collisions.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you for your suggestions! I will try to implement them. However, concerning the coloring I am little bit lost. I have looked into these functions, but could not have figured out how to use them here.Therefore I wrote my own simplistic function.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  This has to be thought through carefully.  The situation is what I said though: VF2 supports edge and vertex coloured *simple* graphs only. It's the most general algorithm available. Another possible solution is to encode the graph like this: [subdivide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)#Subdivision_and_smoothing) each edge so the graph is no longer a multigraph ...

Comment: Check this for ideas too: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22813/12 (what whuber implements is a bit different from the usual coloured isomorphism problem though). Be sure to read the comments.  I'll give this a shot when I'm back. Time to log out now, sorry.

Comment: Do you need to handle mutliple self-loops, e.g. `Graph[{1<->2, 2<->2, 2<->2}]`?   Or will it suffice to allow multi-edges only between distinct vertices?

Comment: Fortunately, only single loops ;)

Comment: @Szabolcs I believe my method deals with such cases.  See the (subsub)section "1-cycles" in my testing file.

Comment: @yarchik I am still not 100% sure what is the best way to make visualization easier. If you'd like to discuss this, or just be notified of new releases, [join the Gitter chatroom](https://gitter.im/IGraphM/Lobby).   I just released v0.3.95. It can pull colours from vertex or edge properties, but this is not really usable with multigraphs due to Mathematica's own limitations ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Hi, thank you, quite busy today, probably another time. However, I have a question concerning your package. How would you prefer it to be cited? Is it published?

Comment: If you are not in a hurry, I'll get a DOI through Zenodo and will write a citation guide for January. I think it is important to keep in mind that most of IGraph/M is based on [igraph](http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-introduction.html#idm470952874400), parts of which are based on other published works (e.g. [bliss](http://www.tcs.hut.fi/Software/bliss/)). If you do cite IGraph/M, it would be appropriate to also cite some of these, especially igraph itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible solution is to find an [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) mapping from coloured multigraphs to coloured simple graphs.  We then test the isomorphism of the transformed graphs with `IGVF2IsomorphicQ`.

My idea for such a mapping is the following:

1. Subdivide every edge `a <-> b` to `a <-> x <-> b`. This eliminates multi-edges between distinct vertices.
2. Subdivide self-loops `a <-> a` to `a <-> x <-> y <-> a`.  This transforms self-loops to 3-cycles.  A 3-cycle cannot be created with the type of subdivision in point 1. above, thus I believe that the injective property of the mapping stands.

The injective property, i.e. that non-isomorphic graphs map to non-isomoprhic ones, is critical. Therefore I encourage you to think through that the above approach is indeed valid.

---

To implement this, we start by introducing a new notation for coloured edges.  `col[a <-> b, c]` represents an edge with colour `c`.  Example:

```
edges = { col[1 <-> 2, 1], col[1 <-> 2, 2], 2 <-> 3 };
```

The following function brings edge representations to a canonical form. Uncoloured edges are assigned the colour `0`.

```
normalizeEdges[edges_] :=
 Block[{TwoWayRule = UndirectedEdge},
  Replace[edges, e_UndirectedEdge -> col[e, 0], {1}]
 ]
```

This function creates a new symbol to be used as a node:

```
newNode[] := Unique[node]
```

Implement subdivision of normal edges and self-loops:

```
subdivide[col[UndirectedEdge[a_, a_], c_]] :=     
 With[{n1 = newNode[], n2 = newNode[]},
  Unevaluated@Sequence[
    col[UndirectedEdge[a, n1], c],
    col[UndirectedEdge[n1, n2], c],
    col[UndirectedEdge[n2, a], c]
    ]
  ]

subdivide[col[UndirectedEdge[a_, b_], c_]] :=
 With[{n1 = newNode[]},
  Unevaluated@Sequence[
    col[UndirectedEdge[a, n1], c],
    col[UndirectedEdge[n1, b], c]
    ]
  ]
```

Convert an edge list in the above format to a subdivided edge list in a format suitable for IGraph/M:

```
colouredSubdividedGraph[edges_] := 
 With[{newEdges = subdivide /@ normalizeEdges[edges]},
  {Graph[newEdges[[All, 1]]], "EdgeColors" -> newEdges[[All, 2]]}
 ]


colouredSubdividedGraph[edges]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Finally, use `IGVF2IsomorphicQ` to compare these transformed coloured graphs.

I won't address the visualization question as that in itself deserves a separate question and has been asked before.

- [Color edges of a multigraph when there are parallel edges using Graph[] and EdgeStyle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/74125/12)
- [Graph: Coloring Edges individually](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84477/12)

Unfortunately, Mathematica cannot properly deal with edge attributes of multigraphs, which makes visualization very messy.  If you feel limited by this problem, I encourage you to report it to Wolfram.

Comment: Thank you! I will try your solution and give little more time in case other people would like to propose a solution.

Answer (score 4):

## Preamble

A few weeks ago I needed to find isomorphisms of colored multigraphs for my research, so I quickly wrote some ugly code that only worked if (a) none of the original colors were the same as the multi-edge counts used to color multi-edges; and (b) multi-edges were not originally colored.  This sloppy 'solution' didn't sit well with me, so I decided to write an answer.

Disclaimers:

1. I haven't tested this terribly throroughly.  Additional suggestions for test code is welcome -- I just don't currently have the willpower to invent exhaustive test cases (partialy because I wrote this code on an overnight flight).  I did make some test cases, with an ad hoc series of assertions that I cooked up.
2. I didn't read the links in Szabolcs' comments.  They might do things better than I do.

## Answer

### Full code

The full code is [on github](https://github.com/jjc385/colored-multigraph-isom).

<sub>If you're really bored, you can look up my horrible original implementation in the earliest version(s).</sub>

**Warning** -- It seems Mathematica 11.2 automatically replaces `\[UndirectedEdge]` with `<->` in `.m` files, but *only upon saving the file*.  I haven't investigated fully, but it seems that some edges are still `\[UndirectedEdge]`'s, while others are `<->`, and `IGraphM` distinguishes between them, so the tests break.  As such, beware that this code will break if you open and save these `.m` files in MMA 11.2.

### Overview

- first combine original colors (I refer to these as `optsColors`, as they are specified in an option-like way to the isomorphism function) with multicolors (computed in the standard way) into a two-element list

  - write these combined 'colors' in an association (associated by edges), in a similar form to the standard color specification
- map each color pair to an integer

  - this is done by adding each unique color pair as a key in a master association, with he `n`th unique color having value `n`.
  - this looks like, e.g., `<| {1,2} -> 1, {2,3} -> 2, ... |>

Note that the keys in this master association can be anything, not necessarily lists of integers

### Colored (and multicolored) multi-edges:

(When I say 'multi-edge', I mean a graph which appears more than once in a multigraph.  For now, I identify directed edges with their reverses.  When I say a multi-edge is colored, I mean that different instances of that edge have different colors.)

If a multi-edge is given a color in the normal way, it is naturally assumed that every instance of that edge has that color.  In order to give different instances of that edge distinct colors, one can specify, e.g., `(1<->2) -> {2,3,4}`, which gives one instance color 2, one color 3, and one color 4, with all others defaulting to zero.

It seems natural to identify different permutations of multi-edge colors -- e.g., `(1<->2) -> {2,3,4}` is identified with `(1<->2) -> {3,2,4}`.  As such, all 'colors' which are lists will be assumed to refer to multi-edges, and will be sorted.

### Further considerations

#### Things left to do

- Deal with directed graphs
- More exhaustive tests
- Figure out a way around the `\[UndirectedEdge]` vs `<->` issue
- Consider type-checking color lists
- Make sure multicolored multi-edges aren't colored with more colors than their multiplicity

#### Minor notes

- I overloaded OP's `decorateGraph` function to work with `IGVF2*` color spec conventions.  See the testing file.

Comment: "Figure out a way around the `\[UndirectedEdge]` vs `<->` issue."  I suggest wrapping relevant functions with `Block[{TwoWayRule = UndirectedEdge}, ...]`.  The next version of IGraph/M [will support](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/commit/f6669eb183491ff798adc13bc0aeada92c7107d5) `TwoWayRule` in isomorphism functions.

Comment: I have not tried your code, but the description is reasonable. An advantage of this transformation compared to mine is that automorphism results (e.g. automorphism group) should be valid as well. With my approach, only isomorphism results will be valid between two graphs. If you use IGraph/M, consider joining [the chatroom](https://gitter.im/IGraphM/Lobby) for any feedback or questions.

Comment: @Szabolcs Could you elaborate on this automorphism issue (perhaps in your answer)?  I'm not sure exactly what you mean, though it now me that when using your method, the output of e.g. `FindIsomorphisms` will need to be processed to eliminate extraneous edges.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm also interested in the performance differences between our methods.  I think mine has the advantage of not having to modify the graph itself, but I'd have to think about whether the processing involved in my method overshadows this advantage.

Comment: @Szabolcs (Last comment, I think)  There's also the issue that my method maps pairs to integers in a way that's dependent upon both graphs, not just one.  But I think that can be fixed by implementing a new syntax which allows these pairs to be computed in advance and passed to isomorphism functions, somewhat similar to your method -- just without modifying the original graph itself.