# Assigning function values in a memoized recursive module

Tags: function-construction, recursion, scoping, memoization

I have a complicated recursive module which I have memoized.
I realised that certain isomorphs of inputs to this function will give the same output. Therefore I decided to memoize all such input-output pairs, each time the function is called with a representative of a new such equivalence class.
Here is a much simpler, analogous module:

First without sneakiness:

```
determinant[m_] := determinant[m] = Module[{localvars},
    If[Length[m] == 1, Return[m[[1, 1]]]];
    Sum[Power[-1, j + 1] m[[1, j]] determinant[
       m[[Complement[Range[Length[m]], {1}], 
         Complement[Range[Length[m]], {j}]]]], {j, 1, Length[m]}]
    ];
```

And now with sneakiness:

```
sneakydeterminant[m_] := sneakydeterminant[m] = Module[{answer},
    If[Length[m] == 1, Return[m[[1, 1]]]];
    answer = 
     Sum[Power[-1, j + 1] m[[1, j]] sneakydeterminant[
        m[[Complement[Range[Length[m]], {1}], 
          Complement[Range[Length[m]], {j}]]]], {j, 1, Length[m]}];
    sneakydeterminant[Transpose[m]] = answer;
    answer
    ];
```

Inspecting the DownValues for each function after calling them seems to indicate that I have succeeded in assigning input-output pairs to the `sneakydeterminant` function, even while inside its own code.

My question is, whether this is allowed and safe, or have I got away with it just by luck ?

The reason I ask is that this doesn't seem to work in my real example (which I refrained from posting because it is many lines of code long).

Thank you !

Comment: I don't see any problems with it, but I find  `sneakydeterminant[m_] := 
 sneakydeterminant[m] = sneakydeterminant[Transpose[m]] = ....` more clear

Comment: Aha ! Very nice !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would write it:

```
sneakydeterminant[m_] := sneakydeterminant[m] = 
  sneakydeterminant[Transpose[m]] = 
    If[Length[m] == 1,
      m[[1, 1]]],
      Sum[Power[-1, j + 1] m[[1, j]] sneakydeterminant[
        m[[Complement[Range[Length[m]], {1}], 
          Complement[Range[Length[m]], {j}]]]], {j, 1, Length[m]}]
```

The only difference is the time at which the new DownValue is added, but it should be equally safe.

Comment: You don't need `Module[{answer}, ...]`

Comment: @belisariusisforth, thanks, missed it, fixed now

Comment: Thank you both very much, belisarius and Marius ! I like how you put the other values in the declaration of the function, and how you used the structure of the If statement. I see you also avoided using `Module`. Is there a similar way to memoize an arbitrary number of equal values of the function ? For instance, suppose that all matrices obtained by permuting the rows and columns like this: `m[[permutation, permutation]]` were supposed to give the same output ?

Comment: @Simon The question about permutations is an interesting one. Perhaps you may post it as a separate one (once you have checked if it wasn't asked before!)

Comment: Thank you belisarius is forth. In fact my matrices are really adjacency matrices of graphs, and I would like to represent unlabelled graphs. Therefore these questions and answers seem as if they might have what I need: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23245/is-there-something-akin-to-subgraphisomorphismq-in-mathematica-9/23247#23247 http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17658/how-can-i-display-a-multigraph-with-different-colored-edges/17685#17685

Comment: It seems that https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html is likely related to what I need. However, it does seem that we would just force Mathematica to try all permutations, which sort of pushes the problem underground. Perhaps this is a philosophical issue - after all our concept of sets having the same cardinality, for instance, concerns the existence of a bijection, which cannot be described without labelling the elements of the sets...

Answer (score 1):

I like this (equivalent) one better:

```
ClearAll[sd];
t = Transpose;
sd@{} = 1;
sd@m_:= sd@m= sd@t@m= m[[1,1]] /; Length@m == 1
sd@m_:= sd@m= sd@t@m= Sum[m[[1,j]] (-1)^(j + 1) sd@Drop[m,{1},{j}], {j, Length@m}]
```

Comment: Thank you ! I must admit that I find the more verbose version much easier to understand !

Comment: @Simon, note that using `Drop` will scale much better than `Complement` for lagre matrices, so +1

Comment: Thank you Marius ! What do you mean by +1- ?

Comment: @Simon He means he upvoted my answer because he has found something of worth in it. I recommend you to the same (meaning: upvotng answers you consider good ones, not necessarily this one :) ). It is just good for future users to know that previous ones considered the content "good"

Comment: @Simon BTW, it doesn't work as a "one time only" prize. You can upvote all the answers you consider good ones.