# Issue with EdgeLabels

Tags: graphs-and-networks, markov-chains

I want to reproduce Shannon's telegraph Markov chain from [A Mathematical Theory of Communication](http://worrydream.com/refs/Shannon%20-%20A%20Mathematical%20Theory%20of%20Communication.pdf).

[image]

`EdgeLabels` isn't doing the trick here:

```
telegraphGraph = Graph[
  {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 
   2 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 2}(*,  
  EdgeLabels \[Rule] {1\[DirectedEdge]2 \[Rule] "DASH", 
  1\[DirectedEdge]2 \[Rule] "DOT", 2\[DirectedEdge]1 \[Rule] 
  "WORD SPACE",  2\[DirectedEdge]1 \[Rule] "LETTER SPACE",
  2\[DirectedEdge]2\[Rule] "DOT", 2\[DirectedEdge] 2\[Rule] 
  "DASH" }*), GraphStyle -> "BasicBlack"]
```

Comment: These are essentially duplicates: [(92014)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92014/12) [(74125)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/74125/12) [(17658)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17658/12)  See the comments under the first one. To keep it simple, I wouldn't use Graph here because properties (such as edge labels) just don't work with multigraphs in Mathematica.  It is a design bug.  Consider writing to Wolfram Support about this, as the more people report the problem the more likely there will be something done about it.

Comment: Thanks @Szabolcs, I'll link this page in an email to WRI's support.

Answer (score 2):

```
edgepoints = {{{1, 0}, {1, 2}, {4, 2}, {4, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {4, 1}, {4, 0}}};
loops = {{4, 0}, {4, 1.5}, {5, .5}, {4, 0}};
textcoords = {{5/2, -1.65}, {5/2, -.9}, {5/2, .9}, {5/2, 1.65}, {4.75, -.5}, {4.75, .5}};
labels = Style[#, 18] & /@ {"WORD SPACE", "LETTER SPACE", "DOT", "DASH", "DASH", "DOT"};
texts = Text @@@ Transpose[{labels, textcoords}]; 

beziercurves = {Arrowheads[{{.05, .7}}], Arrow[BezierCurve@#] & /@ 
    Join[{#, Reverse[{1, -1} # & /@ #]} & /@ edgepoints, {#, {1, -1} # & /@ #} &@loops]};

Graphics[{beziercurves, PointSize[.025], Point[{{1, 0}, {4, 0}}], texts}]
```

[image]