# Graph construction and computing for grouped elements with multiple interactions

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The goal is to build a graph consit of six elements (La, Le ,Li, Ka, Ke, Ki). La, Le, Li belong to group L, while Ka, Ke, Ki belong to group K. There are **two differet interactions** possible between the elements: mailing and meeting (undirected).
In the image below the interactions and groups are shown.
[image]

How can make up this graph in Mathematica? How can I then get a track of a mail to be send from La to Ka? How can I find the link for mailing between the groups in Mathematica? Is it also possible to find tracks that an information, either passed by mailing or meeting, can take from one e.g La to Ki?
I do not want to split it as the construction of the graph may be different with respect to the computations needed.

#### Update

I can built a graph,based on the interactions, like following:

```
Graph[{ "La" <-> "Le", "Le" <-> "Li", "Li" <-> "Ke", "Ke" <-> "Ka", 
  "Li" <-> "Le", "Le" <-> "Ka", "Ka" <-> "Ke", "Ka" <-> "Ki"}, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-12-23-08-27-01.png

But I cannot classify the edge to meet or mail to calculate.

Comment: Interesting question,I want know how to set different edge in a same graph,too.

Comment: Do you need to do this for a large network or is it just for this 6-node example? Do you have raw data that you could post? You may want to let us know what you have done so far.

Answer (score 2):

This is really two problems, rendering and path finding. First let's fake an undirected multi-adjacency matrix graph:

```
spec = DeleteDuplicatesBy[
   {
    "La" <-> "Le", "Le" <-> "Li", "Li" <-> "Ke", "Ke" <-> "Ka", 
    "Li" <-> "Le", "Le" <-> "Ka", "Ka" <-> "Ke", "Ka" <-> "Ki"
    },
   Sort[List @@ #] &
   ];
spec = Flatten[
   spec /. UndirectedEdge[n_, 
      n2_] :> {Property[DirectedEdge[n, n2], 
       EdgeStyle -> Directive[Arrowheads[0], Red]], 
      Property[DirectedEdge[n2, n], 
       EdgeStyle -> Directive[Arrowheads[0], Green]]}];
g=Graph[spec, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Looks like this:

[image: graph]

Then you can apply any path finding algorithm to the adjacency matrix underlying the graph:

```
In[100]:= Normal@AdjacencyMatrix@spec

Out[100]= {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}}
```

This is both the meet path adjacency matrix and the mail path one.

If you then want all mailing/meeting paths, that's pretty easy to do via some Floyd-Warshall like mechanism.

Comment: *How can I then get a track of a mail to be send from La to Ka* from your `graph`?

Comment: Do you want it to go only via mailing routes or is it passed via mail or meet routes? Is one route prioritized? It's a simple-enough problem from a weighted adjacency matrix, but I need more info first.

Comment: And if you want to work directly from the `graph` you can regenerate the matrix via `WeightedAdjacencyMatrix`.

Comment: Yep,I mean *go only via mailing routes*,and *from La to Ka*.

Comment: I just realized I need to tweak the graph generating code (it's only generating a directed mail/meet pair for a pair of nodes, while those edges should really be undirected) but basically just use some variant of Dijkstra's algorithm. It operates on the adjacency matrix.

Comment: So I thought you might have to look at the question again. :)

Comment: @yode Not exactly. I edited the answer to reflect the fact that there are two identical adjacency matrices. The problem is really all in the rendering and by turning off arrows we get the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

As an input I used:

```
vertexData={Property["La","group"->"L"],Property["Le","group"->"L"],Property["Li","group"->"L"],Property["Ka","group"->"K"],Property["Ke","group"->"K"],Property["Ki","group"->"K"]};
linkData=
{Property["La"<->"Le",{EdgeLabels->"mail",EdgeStyle->Blue,"interaction"->"mail"}],
Property["Le"<->"Li",{EdgeLabels->"meet",EdgeStyle->Green,"interaction"->"meet"}],
Property["Le"<->"Li",{EdgeLabels->"mail",EdgeStyle->Blue,"interaction"->"mail"}],
Property["Le"<->"Ka",{EdgeLabels->"meet",EdgeStyle->Green,"interaction"->"meet"}],
Property["Li"<->"Ke",{EdgeLabels->"mail",EdgeStyle->Blue,"interaction"->"mail"}],
Property["Ka"<->"Ke",{EdgeLabels->"meet",EdgeStyle->Green,"interaction"->"meet"}],
Property["Ka"<->"Ke",{EdgeLabels->"mail",EdgeStyle->Blue,"interaction"->"mail"}],
Property["Ka"<->"Ki",{EdgeLabels->"meet",EdgeStyle->Green,"interaction"->"meet"}]};
```

I tried to use the custom property differently but that was what came out in best case. In `Graph` these setting are just ignored. So the passing of an information (able to use "mail" and "meet" edges is just:

```
(*Path for an information to go, as it does not care about different \
interactions as information by definition*)
gFull = Graph[vertexData, linkData, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
infor = FindShortestPath[gFull, "La", "Ki"]
```

> {"La", "Le", "Ka", "Ki"}

To visiualize it I needed to write my own function for the graph and the highlighting

```
(*make edges with its labels for GraphPlot*)
kanten = Flatten[{#[[1, 1]] -> #[[1, 2]]} & /@ linkData];
beschriftung = linkData[[All, 2, 1, 2]];
pltDat = Transpose[{kanten, beschriftung}];
(*Get grouping function*)
vertRand[vert_] := 
 Prepend[Flatten@
    Transpose[{vertexData[[All, 1]], vertexData[[All, 2, 2]]}], 
   vert] /. List -> Switch
(*give a list of verticies then those will be highlighted in Red, you \
can also give an empty list*)
(*Here with Frameimg the Verticies*)
ClearAll[grPltHigh];
grPltHigh[vertLst_: {}, edgLst_: {}] := 
 Module[{highVert = vertLst, highEdge = edgLst, markEdge},
  markEdge = {#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ EdgeList[highEdge]; 
  GraphPlot[pltDat, MultiedgeStyle -> 0.5, 
   EdgeRenderingFunction -> (If[#3 == 
        "mail", {If[(*edge highlighting*)
         MemberQ[markEdge, #2] || MemberQ[markEdge, Reverse@#2], Red, 
         Blue], Thickness[0.009], Line[#1], Black, 
        Inset[#3, Mean[#1], Automatic, Automatic, 
         Background -> Lighter@LightGray]}, {If[(*edge highlighting*)
         MemberQ[markEdge, #2] || MemberQ[markEdge, Reverse@#2], Red, 
         Green], Thickness[0.009], Line[#1], Black, 
        Inset[#3, Mean[#1], Automatic, Automatic, 
         Background -> Lighter@LightGray]}] &),
   VertexRenderingFunction -> (
     If[vertRand[#2] == "L", {Lighter@Orange, EdgeForm[Black],
        If[(*for highlighting as underlying rectangle in Red is made*) 
         MemberQ[highVert, #2], {Red, 
          Rectangle[#1 - {boxSize, boxSize}*1.3, #1 + {boxSize, 
              boxSize}*1.3]}], 
        Rectangle[#1 - {boxSize, boxSize}, #1 + {boxSize, boxSize}], 
        Black, Text[#2, #1]},
       If[vertRand[#2] == "K", {LightBlue, EdgeForm[Black],
         If[(*for highlighting as underlying rectangle in Red is made*)
          MemberQ[highVert, #2], {Red, 
           Rectangle[#1 - {boxSize, boxSize}*1.3, #1 + {boxSize, 
               boxSize}*1.3]}], 
         Rectangle[#1 - {boxSize, boxSize}, #1 + {boxSize, boxSize}], 
         Black, Text[#2, #1]}]] &)]
```

use grPltHigh[*vertex list*,*edge list*] or grPltHigh[] for pure graph

Usage with the result infor:

```
grPltHigh[{}, PathGraph[infor]]
```

> [image]

I acctually hoped to use the custom property directly in calculations (e.g. setting `EdgeWeight` from it in `FindShortestPath`). Instead I have to use a filter function to derive different graphs for the according links "mail" or "meet".

```
(*This function filters the needed item per property*)
edgeFilter[inList_,filtProp_,filtItem_]:=Module[{inLst=inList,fltPrp=filtProp,fltIt=filtItem,ergLst},
ergLst=fltPrp/.#[[2]]&/@inLst(*Uses the List of Property for each edge to retrieve its value*);
Pick[inLst,ergLst,filtItem](*Gives only the edges that contain the item of property*)
];
```

Using it for getting a mail path between La and Ke:

```
gMail=Graph[edgeFilter[linkData,"interaction","mail"],VertexLabels->"Name"];
mailShort=FindShortestPath[gMail,"La","Ke"];
grPltHigh[{},PathGraph@mailShort]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

It is done for "meet" pathes accordingly.
To find the links between the groups one needs to setup a group graph. I have done it by replacing the vertex names with the group names and getting only the edges between different groups.

```
(*Derive a list of replacement for the vertex with its group*)
replRuleGroup=Flatten[{#[[1]]->#[[2,2]]}&/@vertexData];
(*Replace the vertex name by the group name*)
groupData=linkData/.replRuleGroup;
(*Pick only links that go from one group to the other*)
interGroup=Not[#[[ 1, 1]]==#[[1, 2]]]&/@groupData;
groupLink=Pick[groupData,interGroup,True]
```

In this case the result is the two edges from K group to L group.

> {Property[
>     "L" <-> "K", {EdgeLabels -> "meet", EdgeStyle -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0], 
>      "interaction" -> "meet"}], 
>    Property["L" <-> "K", {EdgeLabels -> "mail", 
>      EdgeStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1], "interaction" -> "mail"}]}

In the end it was way more complicated than assumed. The "custom property" in `Property` would be more usefull if it could be used in graph related functions as a filter property e.g. for `EgdeCost`, `EdgeWeight`, `EdgeCapacity`. I did played around with it a lot but ended up with nothing better than this long solution above. Quite disappointing. I really would like to know how to make proper use of "custom property" in `Property`.

Comment: I note that `gFull` not very same to the the topic?

Comment: If you see it drawn, it is wrong I agree. Therefore I wrote an own function for drawing. For the purpose of finding a path from one to another vertex it works as MMA does not makes a difference whatever the "interaction" item is. Graph overwrites the `EdgeStyle` definitions of edges linking the same vertecies.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the representation of a *multigraph* you can have a look at this question: [How can I display a multigraph with different colored edges?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17658/how-can-i-display-a-multigraph-with-different-colored-edges).

Finding out which nodes are reachable you can use `FindPath` and `FindShortestPath`.

Comment: Have you read the original question?Which don't mean that color demand maybe.

Comment: @yode If you refer to the linked article you will see that it does represent multigraphs and that different colors can be used to represent different types of edges (1=mail, 2=meet, etc.). Les us know if something is unclear.